# Win10 Enterprise without IIS in Windows Features

Tags: windows, iis, visual-studio-2019

I have Win 10 Enterprise with Visual Studio 2019 (with IIS Express) , but I cannot include IIS because don't have the iis folder in Windows Features 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHJgZ.png)

Comment: If you mean you cannot see "Internet Information Services" there like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7#install-iis-7-or-above, then your only hope is to talk to your system administrators and learn how to fix that. The original Windows installation media always includes IIS, but administrators can decide to remove it.

Comment: Yes, I wrote about "Internet Information Services". Well, apparently, I have incorrect OS..

Comment: It looks like either OS is not installed correctly or you have installed the incorrect version. Could you install IIS via powershell  Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server?